# How to disable updates during migration?

Tags: 7, migrations

[image]

For the past couple years, something has confounded me about [Drupal Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate): there is a `--update` option and a `--needs-update` option when using Drush, but Migrate seems to update on it's own without using either of these options.

Seems like drush needs a `--no-update` option IMO.

My problem is, I have over 100K files that need to be migrated, and I'm having issues like the following:

```
drush mi ImageAttachFileMigration --limit=10000
Processed 10000 (0 created, 10000 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) in 311.4 sec
```

That doesn't happen every time, but I'm lucky to get a few hundred created.

This is my code in hook_register_migrations():

```
  // File Migration for Image Attach Images
  $file_arguments = $common_arguments + array(
    'machine_name' => 'ImageAttachFileMigration',
    'description' => t('Import Drupal 6 File references to be used by content types that used image attach in D6.'),
    'user_migration' => 'RanchoUserMigration', // User migration must be run first so the ownership can be set.
    'default_uid' => 1,  // Seems appropriate
    'source_dir' => 'http://example.com/',  // See https://www.drupal.org/node/1540106
  );
  Migration::registerMigration('DrupalFile6Migration', $file_arguments['machine_name'], $file_arguments);
```

I know there's [a way to disable hooks](https://www.drupal.org/node/2136601), but I'm not even sure what's triggering the update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you overriding the hash function? Could you paster your migrate map class?

Comment: @jorgetutor I added the only code I have for this just now.